# Adding a Select Box Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am creating an application using JSP.
In one of the Pages , the user needs to enter some Symptoms . Now i want to give a  button. when the user clicks this button , a new select box is created .

I have searched a lot and can only find how to dynamically add options to select but i want new select box

Someone please help .

Comment: posting some of the code that you have already will help you get an answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addSelectBox ()
        {
            var parentDiv = document.getElementById ("main");
            var selectElement = document.createElement ("select");
            for (var i=0;i < 5;i++)
            {
                var option = new Option ("Text " + i, "Value" + i);
                selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = option;
            }
            parentDiv.appendChild (selectElement);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
        <input type="button" onclick="addSelectBox ()" name="clickme" value="Add Select Box" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

For JSP (if you have the options in an ArrayList):

```
    <html>
      <head>
<%
      int totalElements = 5;
      ArrayList r = new ArrayList (totalElements);
      for (int i=1;i <= totalElements;i++)
      {
         r.add (String.valueOf (i));
      }
%>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addSelectBox ()
            {
                var parentDiv = document.getElementById ("main");
                var selectElement = document.createElement ("select");
                var option;
<%
                for (int i=0;i <= r.size();i++)
                {
%>
                    option = new Option ('<%=r.get (i)%>', '<%=r.get (i)%>');
                    selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = option;
<%
                }
%>
                parentDiv.appendChild (selectElement);
            }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="main">
            <input type="button" onclick="addSelectBox ()" name="clickme" value="Add Select Box" />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply . The Code is working fine but i have got all the symptoms in an ArrayList and when i am trying to use that while defining the options ... it is not working...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function addSelectBox ()
        {
            var parentDiv = document.getElementById ("main");
            var selectElement = document.createElement ("select");
            for(var i=0;i<r.size();i++)
            {
                var option = new Option(r.get(i),r.get(i));
                selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = option;
            }
            parentDiv.appendChild (selectElement);
        }
 </script>

Comment: You mean javascript Array or java ArrayList? For Javascript Array, use it like r[i] instead of r.get (i) which is java notation.

Comment: Java and javascript are separate language. java runs on server while javascript runs on the client browser. Check my edit to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".your-button").click(function() {
    var selectBoxHtml = ["<select>"];
    var sourceItems = [4,5,6];
    for (var sourceIndex = 0; sourceIndex < sourceItems.length; sourceIndex++) {
        selectBoxHtml.push('<option value="' + sourceIndex + '">' + sourceItems[sourceIndex] + '</option');
    }
    $(this).after(selectBoxHtml.join("") + "</select>");
});
```

Once sourceItems is dynamic, be sure to escape it.